# Ubuntu runs in Low Graphics mode after modifying Lightdm.conf

Tags: graphics, xorg, lightdm

I wanted to disable the guest login in my Ubuntu 14.04, so I opened the lightdm configuration file using:

`sudo gedit etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`

But the file was **Empty** (There were NO lines like [SeatDeafaults] etc.. )
So I added following line in that file:

**allow-guest=false**

and saved the config file and restarted my laptop.

On restart it ran in low graphics mode.
So I was unable to try following to restore it to previous state:
`sudo gedit etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`

Also, after pressing trl+Alt+F1 at window showing message of "Low Graphics Mode", I logged with my credentials and tried

`sudo nano etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`

But when I tried to save the changes, it was showing the file doesn't exist.
Also **failsafeX** is not working for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create bootable USB Drive with Ubuntu using Startup Disk Creator software (which is pre-installed with stock ubbuntu) on another PC/Laptop.

Boot from this USB drive and select 1st option **"Try Ubuntu without installing".**

Then Ubuntu Desktop loads up, go to **System Settings >> User Accounts**.

Create an Administrative account Enable it (by clicking on Account Disabled. You may have to choose a password for this account).

Then log in to this account (by clicking on Wheel icon in the **Top-Right** of screen then clicking on New Account).

After logging into Administrative account you created on Live Ubuntu on USB Drive, open terminal and type

`sudo nautilus`

and from there go to **Computer>>etc>>lightdm**

Open lightdm.conf file in the lightdm folder and add following lines:

`[SeatDefaults]`

`greeter-session=unity-greeter`

Now Save the file and Restart the system.

If your problem is due to driver related problems check answers to this question:
[How to fix “The system is running in low-graphics mode” error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error)